# How I get the record of two table which don't have foreign key relationship?

Tags: mysql

Hi Anyone can help me to solve this problem

I have 3 tables `FundsPlanning` , `GradeMst` and `SupplierMst`

I want column `SupplierId`, `WeightLoaded`, `DeliveryDate`, `InvoiceAmount`, `GradeName`
like this way.

But the problem is there is no relationship between `FundsPlanning` and `GradeMst`.

So the `GradeName` column exists in GradeMst table.

There is also one table `PurchaseContract` which has a foreignkey relationship with
`SupplierId` and `GradeId` so I can find the Id of Grade.

Using below query I can get the record of Grade column

```sql
SELECT GradeId, Grade 
FROM GradeMst 
WHERE GradeId In (SELECT Gradeid FROM PurchaseContract WHERE SupplierId=2)
```

Using below query I can find the `SupplierId`, `WeightLoaded`, `DeliveryDate`, `InvoiceAmount`.

```sql
SELECT FP.SupplierId,SM.SupplierId,FP.WeightLoaded,FP.DeliveryDate,FP.InvoiceAmount 
FROM FundsPlanning FP
INNER JOIN SupplierMst SM
ON FP.SupplierId=SM.SupplierId and SM.SupplierId=2
```

How can I combine the result set of these two tables?

[image: How to combine result of two queries]

Comment: Hi Geeta, Can you post the queries, results and expected output as text instead of images;
With a proper formatting. People can surely help you.

Comment: when you have tables you want to join together you have to look for common data - if they have columns with data in common (even though they are not defined as foreign key columns) that have the proper relationship (e.g. 1: many) you can build a join where you use the columns, even though the foreign key relationship has not been formally defined. be aware though, that the integrity of the data may lead to odd results (values that don't exist in the "parent" table for instance). You may also have to join on a combination of several columns to get the data

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort to help me out of this problem. I have tried to solve this using the below query and I got the result, but right now I don't know whether it will be full filled the requirement of the client or not.

Comment: Select * from (
select FP.SupplierId,FP.WeightLoaded,FP.DeliveryDate,FP.InvoiceAmount 
From FundsPlanning FP
INNER JOIN SupplierMst SM
ON FP.SupplierId=SM.SupplierId
and SM.SupplierId=@SupplierId and FP.DeliveryDate >= @Year ) As FP_SM
cross join (
select GradeId, Grade as GradeName from GradeMst where GradeId In 
 (Select Gradeid from PurchaseContract where SupplierId=2)
) As FP_SM_GM
) as TblFinal  group by GradeName

Answer (score 1):

You could try to join all tables, but you need to take care of the relationships between tables (1-1, 1-many, many-many) because you could end up getting duplicate rows

```sql
SELECT
    FP.SupplierId,
    SM.SupplierId,
    FP.WeightLoaded,
    FP.DeliveryDate,
    FP.InvoiceAmount,
    GM.GradeName
FROM FundsPlanning FP, 
    SupplierMst SM,
    PurchaseContract PC,
    GradeMst GM
WHERE 
    FP.SupplierId = SM.SupplierId 
    AND PC.SupplierId = FP.SupplierId
    AND GM.GradeId = PC.GradeId
    AND SM.SupplierId = 2
```

Comment: Great, hope you accept the answer if it was useful!